# Check Status of remote windows desktop using java program

Tags: java

I want to check the status of remote desktop,whether the remote desktop is up and running through java code.

I am able to check Linux server/desktop using jsch api.

Comment: do you mean for windows ?

Comment: Yes.I want status for windows.